# Resubmit Search Results From Array Back To MySQL DB with hidden fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

my first post on here, even though I am a regular visitor to this very helpful site

I wonder if someone can please help me with the following:

I am writing a simple stock check solution for my company in PHP with MySQL, im still a novice but learning.

We have the following search form that shows results from a database when the barcode of the product is entered, what I am looking to do is have a button at the bottom of the results that says "Checked OK", which resubmits the info back to the database, updates the timestamp, and has a hidden field to change the "status" to checked.

The database name is "stock"
The table name is "main_stock"
The fields are:
id
curr_timestamp
mastercategory
category
product_desc
barcode
serial
status

Each search only gives one result as the barcodes are unique

The bit i am stuck on is how to get the result into a form to be able to resubmit them back into the database

This is only for internal use within a protected network, any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Jon

```
    <?php



    $dbHost = 'localhost'; // localhost will be used in most cases

    // set these to your mysql database username and password.

    $dbUser = 'xxxxxxxx'; 
    $dbPass = 'xxxxxxx';
    $dbDatabase = 'stock'; // the database you put the table into.

    $con = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL         Server. Error: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbDatabase) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to database {$dbDatabase}.         Error: " . mysql_error());

    // Set up our error check and result check array

    $error = array();
    $results = array();

    // First check if a form was submitted. 
    // Since this is a search we will use $_GET

    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {   
    $searchTerms = trim($_GET['search']);   
    $searchTerms = strip_tags($searchTerms); // remove any html/javascript.      

    if (strlen($searchTerms) < 2) {      
    $error[] = "Search terms must be longer than 2 characters.";   
    }else {      
    $searchTermDB = mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerms); // prevent sql injection.   
    }      

    // If there are no errors, lets get the search going.   

    if (count($error) < 1) {      
    $searchSQL = "SELECT mastercategory, category, product_desc, barcode, serial FROM main_stock         WHERE ";            

    // grab the search types.      
    $types = array();      
    $types[] = isset($_GET['barcode'])?"`barcode` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":''; 
    $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not         checked)            

    if (count($types) < 1)         
    $types[] = "`barcode` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked                

    $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';      
    $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `barcode`"; // order by title.      
    $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" .         mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");            

    if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {         
    $error[] = "The scanned barcode {$searchTerms} is not in the database.";      
    }else {         
    $results = array(); // the result array         
    $i = 1;         
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {            
    $results[] = "{$i}:Product Name&nbsp;:&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['product_desc']}        <br />Master Category&nbsp;:&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['mastercategory']}<br />Sub         Category&nbsp;:&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['category']}<br />Barcode&nbsp;:&nbsp;{$row['barcode']}        <br />Serial No.&nbsp;:&nbsp;{$row['serial']}";            
    $i++;         
    }      
    }   
    }
    }
    function removeEmpty($var) {   
    return (!empty($var)); 
    }?>

    <html>   

    <title>Search Form</title>   
    <BODY onLoad="document.forms.searchForm.search.focus()">  
    <form action="index.php">
  <center>
    <span class="formcentjc">
      <input type=submit value="Home" />
      </span>
  </center>
</form>  
    <?php echo (count($error) > 0)?"The following had errors:<br /><span id=\"error\">" . implode("<br />", $error) . "</span><br /><br />":""; ?>      

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="GET" name="searchForm" class="cent">
    <onLoad="document.searchForm.search()">
    <table width="196" border="1">
     <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#D6D6D6" style="text-align: center" scope="col">Search For:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: center">
        <td class="cent1">
          <input name="search" type="text" onFocus="this.value='';" value="<?php echo isset        ($searchTerms)?htmlspecialchars($searchTerms):''; ?>" size="28" maxlength="15" />
          <span style="text-align: center"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form> 
    <p>
     <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#D6D6D6"><form action="addproduct.php">
          <center>
             <span class="formcentjc">
              <input type=submit value="Add New Product" />
              </span>
          </center>
        </form></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </p>

    <?php 
    echo (count($results) > 0)?"SUCCESS: {$searchTerms} :<br /><br />" . implode("", $results):""; 
    ?>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The idea here is to grab the data from the database, and re-populate the form. When I build pages like this, I usually have a parameter in the URL contains the primary key of the MySQL row, I want to grab, like this `mypage.php?id=37`.

If `$_GET['id']` is set and is numeric, then I run a query like this:

```
$id = mysqli::real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$data = mysqli::query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}'");

//Check to see if we got any data back :)
```

Then, we can populate the form again:

```
<input name="value1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo stripslashes($data['value1'])" />
```

Once the data is submitted from the user again, then run a query like this:

```
$id = mysqli::real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$value1 = mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['value1']);
$value2 = mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['value2']);
mysqli::query("UPDATE table SET value1='{$value1}', value2='{$value2}' ... WHERE id = '{$id}' LIMIT 1");
```

**Edit:**

From what I gather, your button on the detail page will submit (I'm guessing the product name  of) one of the returned products back into the database, along with the time it was searched, and a status, of some sort.

As you loop through the array of fetched results to display them to the user, I would gather the name of the product and push it on an array like this:

```
$fetchedProducts = array();

while (/*Loop condition to loop through fetched results*/) {
  array_push($loopVariable['productName'], $fetchedProducts);

  //Build HTML to display results
}

//Insert into database
$products = mysqli::real_escape_string(json_encode($fetchedProducts));
$timestamp = strtotime("now");
$status = "some status";

mysqli::query("INSERT INTO searchRecords (
                  `id`, `products`, `timestamp`, `status`
               ) VALUES (
                  NULL, '{$products}', '{$timestamp}', '{$status}'
               )");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will give that a go and post back

Comment: No problem! Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: @Jon If you found my post helpful, please consider hitting the up arrow to up vote my answer, and selecting the checkmark to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Hi again, sorry Im a bit stuck with this, the search page has a simple inputbox, where the barcode is entered, the submit is pressed, then the page refreshes to the result page, I can get the barcode to pass to the adrress bar,but cant figure out how to get the id field to, as this isnt searched for on the initial page, the id field is the primary index. I have looked at redoing the search script, but everything I can find passes what is searched for to the address bar, and not a field from the DB, sorry I think Im confussing myself

Comment: @Jon If I am understanding your correctly, you have passed all of the values from the form into the URL as parameters. You do not necessarily need to supply an `id` parameter (or whatever your database's primary key is), you can simply search by the barcode like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE barcode = '{$myBarcode}`. Did I answer your question?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being very clear, a barcode is entered into a text box, then submit is pressed, the page (detailed in my question) is submitted to itself using get, then the resultant fields are put in an array and displayed on the page, what I want is a button on that page to submit the product back into the database, and two hidden fields that updates the timestamp field, and status field

Comment: @Jon I've updated my answer. I tried to explain how I understood your last comment. Let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I think that is just what i need, and as far as I can tell will do what I need, unfortunatly, when testing it I get the following error in the logs "PHP Fatal error:  Non-static method mysqli::real_escape_string() cannot be called statically"

Comment: @Jon Replace `mysqli::real_escape_string()` with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Thanks again for the update, I have changed the above, the form now submits, but i get all fields reported as undefined variables in the PHP error log, and nothing changes in the database

Comment: I would suggest using `$_GET['search']` to get the value of the search input. Don't forget to escape input using `mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['search'])`.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your reply, I think i am nearly there now, just getting the following errors: PHP Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given in /var/www/stocktest/search.php on line 172 line 172 is $product_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string(json_encode($con, $results)); and also 'code' PHP Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in , this also points to the same line

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I haven't used that method much. Since your sample shows that you are using the mysql_* rather than the mysqli_* library, use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, instead (not mysqli...). The mysql_* extension is deprecated (http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). I would suggest moving to the PDO libarary or the MySQLi library.